# Static Null Injector Error NGX-Bootstrap Tabs Module w/ Angular 8

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I have two modules in my application. `AppModule` and a `NPOModule`.

`AppModule` imports `NPOModule` here:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavMenuComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    NPOModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    NgxSpinnerModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

`NPOModule` is lazy loaded and is attempting to use ngx-bootstrap tabset but returning a static null injector error in console when attempting to navigate to the route.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NpoComponent } from './npo/npo.component';
import { NpoNewComponent } from './npo-new/npo-new.component';
import { NPORoutingModule } from './npo-routing.module';

import { TabsModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/tabs';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [NpoComponent, NpoNewComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    NPORoutingModule,
    TabsModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: []
})
export class NPOModule { }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="card-body">
  <div>
   <tabset #registerNPOTabs>
    <tab heading="Basic Info" id="tab1">Basic content</tab>
    <tab heading="NPO Registration">Basic content 1</tab>
   </tabset>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've read all the documentation and don't see where I'm implementing this incorrectly.

The error is:

```
stack: 'NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[TabsetComponent -> TabsetConfig]: \n' +
      '  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[TabsetComponent -> TabsetConfig]: \n' +
      '    NullInjectorError: No provider for TabsetConfig!\n' +
```

Comment: Can you add to your question the actual error?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Duh! Updated the op